# Why PHP doesn't allow anonymous functions inside CONST?

Tags: php, oop, syntax, php-5.3

Why this code isn't allowed in PHP?

```
const VALIDATOR = array(
    'field' => array(
        'type' => 'string',
        'custom' => function() {
            return true;
    }));
```

Or even this simpler version?

```
const MY_FUN = function($param) {
            echo $param;
    };
```

An `unexpected T_FUNCTION` error is thrown.

Comment: `A constant is an identifier (name) for a __simple value__` an array or an anonymous function are __not__ simple

Comment: another question lead here so i post here something can work(work here also)  <?php
  function yeah(){ 
   echo ' hello again from '.phpversion();
  }

  class complicated{
   public static function yeah(){
    echo 'same stuff';
   }
  }

  define('yeah' , 'complicated::yeah');
  echo (yeah)(); 
  echo yeah();
 
?>

i got :
same stuff hello again from 8.0.0


or
same stuff hello again from 8.1.0alpha3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other answers only copy the manual. I will try to explain the real problem of the function constant idea.

PHP can not introduce function constant even the behavior of a function can be determined in compile time. This is because PHP allow function and const have the SAME name, which means if PHP allowed function constant, such code

```
function test() {}

const test = function () {};
```

will be ambiguous for `test()` invoke.

Constant and function can have the same name is very weird, and definitely WRONG design in my opinion, but they already be there from the first day, and can not be removed or will break compatibility.

Note, in theory, introduce function constant may NOT break compatibility. PHP can add an exception rule that do not allow same name function and const only if it is a function constant (there is no function constant in the past, so will not break compatibility). But it's still not enough. Another exception rule is need for

```
use function A\test;
use const B\test;
```

if B\test is a function constant.

But the engine never know whether B\test is a function constant, until the code of B\test is included/autoloaded. Postpone namespace resolving to runtime is not acceptable in any ways, so the only possibility is throw runtime exception. But most of us treat namespace as a static feature and will never expect such runtime exception.

So I think PHP will never allow function constant.

Answer (score 8):

Because it has to be a **constant** value, since you define a constant! So you can't assign "dynamic" values to a constant otherwise it wouldn't be constant.

You can also read/see this in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php):

> Only **scalar data (boolean, integer, float and string)** can be contained in constants prior to PHP 5.6. From PHP 5.6 onwards, it is **possible** to define a constant as a **scalar expression**, and it is also possible to define an **array constant**. It is possible to define constants as a resource, but it should be avoided, as it can cause unexpected results.

Comment: Anonymous function is in no way dynamic value.
It's a constant calculating expression of which value in memory doesn't change. The dynamic thing is what it produces, not the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

[`const`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) should be a scalar in PHP.

> The value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a property, a result of a mathematical operation, or a function call.